# XSLT to remove spaces from text nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to trim extra spaces from text values of my XML. I tried various options available over internet but none of them worked for me.
I cannot use **normalize-space()** because I have to remove only leading & trailing spaces.

XML:

```
<BillEvent>
<TransactionInfo>
    <EventDate>   2016-04-13T05:40:28  </EventDate>
   </TransactionInfo>  
         <CaseID>    Since     this   is a CDATA section! </CaseID>
        <BillGroup>
                <Bill>   
                <BillNumber>     253545666847</BillNumber>
                <ToDate> 2016-05-31     </ToDate>
                <BillActivityCode tc="1"/>
                <BillCreationDate>     Since this is a CDATA section!   </BillCreationDate>
            </Bill>
        </BillGroup>       
</BillEvent>
```

Expected output:

```
<BillEvent>
<TransactionInfo>
    <EventDate>2016-04-13T05:40:28</EventDate>
   </TransactionInfo>  
         <CaseID>Since     this   is a CDATA section!</CaseID>
        <BillGroup>
                <Bill>   
                <BillNumber>253545666847</BillNumber>
                <ToDate>2016-05-31</ToDate>
                <BillActivityCode tc="1"/>
                <BillCreationDate>Since this is a CDATA section!</BillCreationDate>
            </Bill>
        </BillGroup>       
</BillEvent>
```

i.e. only leading & trailing spaces should be removed.

XSLT used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version ="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method ="xml" indent = "yes" cdata-section-elements="BillCreationDate"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:sequence-of select="replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '')"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also tried `translate(.,' &#x9;&#xa;&#xd;', '')` & `replace(.,'^ +','')`. I am not sure what is wrong with my code because of which none of them worked.
I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression in `replace` is correct. The problem is that you you have an `xsl:copy` in your template, which copies the text as-is, and it then doesn't make sense to try to add something as a child of a text node.

Additionally, `xsl:sequence-of` is not a valid command (although that maybe a typo in your question).

Try this template...

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Actually I was trying this on a tool available online which was throwing error - `Not valid.
FatalError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: replace
FatalError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: function token not found.
FatalError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException` so I changed it to **xsl:sequence-of** & I added copy because it was not printing any text value at all. Anyways, my bad. Tried your code in a different tool where it worked as expected. Thanks. :)

Comment: `replace` only works in XSLT 2.0, so the first tool you tried probably only supported XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Yeah may be, from now onward, I will check all these details before trying.